# $~A:=\text{matrix} ~\rightarrow~\lim_{n\to\infty}A^{n}=?~;~$How should I approach against it first?

Tags: linear-algebra, limits, systems-of-equations, exponentiation

$$A:=\begin{pmatrix} \alpha&1-\alpha\\1-\beta&\beta\\\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\left(0<\alpha,\beta<1\right)~~\wedge~~\left(\alpha+\beta\neq 1\right)$$
$$\underbrace{\lim_{n\to\infty}A^{n}}_{\text{What can I do?}}$$
The problem didn't specified whether$~n~$is an natural number.

I think this problem is of a quite typical problem.

$$\det\left(B-\lambda I\right)$$

$$=\det\left( \begin{matrix} \alpha-\lambda&1-\alpha\\ 1-\beta&\beta-\lambda\\ \end{matrix}\right)$$
$$=\det\left(\left(\alpha-\lambda\right)\left(\beta-\lambda\right)-\left(1-\alpha\right)\left(1-\beta\right)\right)$$
$$=\det\left(\left(\lambda-\alpha\right)\left(\lambda-\beta\right)-\left(\alpha-1\right)\left(\beta-1\right)\right)$$
$$=\det\left(\lambda^{2}-\left(\alpha+\beta\right)\lambda+\alpha\beta-\left(\alpha\beta-\alpha-\beta+1\right)\right)$$
$$=\det\left(\lambda^{2}-\left(\alpha+\beta\right)\lambda+\alpha\beta-\alpha\beta+\alpha+\beta-1\right)$$
$$=\det\left(\lambda^{2}-\left(\alpha+\beta\right)\lambda+\left(\left(\alpha+\beta\right)-1\right)\right)$$
$$\lambda=\frac{\left(\alpha+\beta\right)\pm\sqrt{\left(\alpha+\beta\right)^{2}-4\left(\left(\alpha+\beta\right)-1\right)}}{2}$$
About inside the square root.
$$\left(\alpha+\beta\right)^{2}-4\left(\left(\alpha+\beta\right)-1\right)$$
$$=\left(\alpha+\beta\right)^{2}-4\left(\alpha+\beta\right)+4$$
$$=\left(\left(\alpha+\beta\right)-2\right)^{2}\geq0$$

$$\therefore~~~\lambda=\frac{\left(\alpha+\beta\right)\pm\sqrt{\left(\left(\alpha+\beta\right)-2\right)^{2}}}{2}$$

$$=\frac{\left(\alpha+\beta\right)\pm\sqrt{\left(2-\left(\alpha+\beta\right)\right)^{2}}}{2}$$

$$=\frac{\left(\alpha+\beta\right)\pm\left|2-\left(\alpha+\beta\right)\right|}{2}$$

Since$~\alpha+\beta<2~$is held,

$$\lambda=\frac{\left(\alpha+\beta\right)\pm\left(2-\left(\alpha+\beta\right)\right)}{2}~~\leftarrow~~\text{Removed operator of absolute value}$$
$$\lambda^{+}=\frac{\left(\alpha+\beta\right)+\left(2-\left(\alpha+\beta\right)\right)}{2}$$
$$=1$$
$$\lambda^{-}=\frac{\left(\alpha+\beta\right)-\left(2-\left(\alpha+\beta\right)\right)}{2}$$
$$=\frac{\left(\alpha+\beta\right)-2+\left(\alpha+\beta\right)}{2}$$
$$=\frac{2\left(\alpha+\beta\right)-2}{2}$$
$$=\left(\alpha+\beta\right)-1$$

$$\therefore~~~\lambda=1,\underbrace{\left(\alpha+\beta\right)-1}_{\neq0}$$

---

$$p_{A}\left(x\right)=x^{2}-sx+s-1$$
$$n\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq2}$$
$$q\left(x\right)=n-2~\text{degree polynomial}$$
$$a_{n},b_{n}\in\mathbb{R}$$

$$\underbrace{x^{n}=q\left(x\right)p_{A}\left(x\right)+a_{n}x+b_{n}}_{\text{I've been struggling to derive it}}$$

$$x^{n}=q\left(x\right)p_{A}\left(x\right)+a_{n}x+b_{n}$$
$$=\left\{\text{const}_{n-2}x^{n-2}+\sum_{i=0}^{n-3?}\text{const}_{i}x^{i}\right\}\left(x^{2}-sx+s-1\right)+a_{n}x+b_{n}$$

About above, at least, I can understand that RHS of the above equation is n degree polynomial but unable to prove that other$~x^{i}~~\leftrightarrow~~i\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\left\{n-2\right\}~$disappears.

I think as$~n~$is greater than 2, then any const takes zero hence$~a_n, b_n~$is always zero except as n is 2.

Comment: Generally the use of $n$ implies an integer variable. Anyway, it's a standard kind of problem where you need to diagonalize, or at least do enough of the diagonalization to get the limiting behavior (so all the eigenvalues and potentially some of the eigenvectors).

Comment: Ok, I will firstly derive eigenvectors. Indeed,  I already have got the eigenvalues.

Comment: Keep in mind that the limit will only actually exist if all the eigenvalues are either inside the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$ or exactly $1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial $p_A$ of $A$ is given by

\begin{eqnarray}
p_A(x)&=&(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)-(1-\alpha)(1-\beta)\cr
&=&x^2-sx+s-1
\end{eqnarray}

where $s=\alpha+\beta$.  The eigenvalues are therefore

\begin{eqnarray}
\lambda&=&\frac{s \pm \sqrt{s^2-4(s-1)}}{2} \cr
&=&\frac{s \pm \sqrt{(s-2)^2}}{2} \cr
&=&\frac{s \pm (2-s)|}{2} \cr
&=&\frac{(1\mp1)s \pm 2}{2} \cr
\lambda_1&=&s-1 \in (-1,1)\cr
\lambda_2&=&1
\end{eqnarray}

For any positive integer $n \ge 2$, there exist a polynomial $q$ of degree $n-2$ and real coefficients $a_n, b_n$  such that
$$\tag{1}
x^n=q(x)p_A(x)+a_nx+b_n
$$
Since $p_A(\lambda)=0$, we have

\begin{eqnarray}
a_n+b_n&=&1\cr
a_n\lambda_1+b_n&=&\lambda_1^n
\end{eqnarray}
i.e.
\begin{eqnarray}
a_n&=&\frac{\lambda_1^n-1}{\lambda_1-1}\cr
b_n&=&\frac{\lambda_1^n-\lambda_1}{1-\lambda_1}
\end{eqnarray}
Using (1), we have
$$
A^n=a_nA+b_nI
$$
Because $|\lambda_1|<1$, we have  $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}\lambda_1^n=0$
and
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=\frac{-1}{\lambda_1-1}, \quad 
\lim_{n\to \infty}b_n=\frac{-\lambda_1}{1-\lambda_1}
$$
Hence
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}A^n=\frac{-1}{\lambda_1-1}A+\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1-1}I=
\left(
\begin{array}[cc]
1\frac{\beta-1}{\alpha+\beta-2}& \frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha+\beta-2}\cr
\frac{\beta-1}{\alpha+\beta-2} & \frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha+\beta-2}
\end{array}
\right).
$$

Comment: Currently I am struggling understanding eqn1 which you have given. 

Which keyword(s) you think is/are good to be searched to understand it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#Euclidean_division

This(Euclidean division) is helpful to it for me.