# Proof of $~\exists~~q\left(x\right)~\text{and}~a_{n},b_{n}\in\mathbb{R}\ni x^{n}=q\left(x\right)f\left(x\right)+a_{n}x+b_{n}~$

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

My this post is a subproblem of [this post mine(equation1of post of answer)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4304736/a-textmatrix-rightarrow-lim-n-to-inftyan-how-should-i-approac/4304807#4304807).

$$f\left(x\right)=ax^{2}+bx+c~~\leftarrow~a,b,c~\text{are non-zero constants}$$
$$n\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq2}$$

I want to prove the following.
$$q\left(x\right):=n-2~\text{degree polynomial}$$

$$\exists~~q\left(x\right)~\text{and}~a_{n},b_{n}\in\mathbb{R}\ni x^{n}=q\left(x\right)f\left(x\right)+a_{n}x+b_{n}$$
As$~n=2~$is held, it is easy to derive.
$$x^{2}=\underbrace{q\left(x\right)}_{\text{degree of 0}}\left(ax^{2}+bx+c\right)+a_{2}x+b_{2}$$

$$\text{const}:=\text{constant term}=q\left(x\right)$$

$$x^{2}=\text{const}\left(ax^{2}+bx+c\right)+a_{2}x+b_{2}$$
$$=\text{const}\cdot a x^{2}+\text{const}\cdot bx+\text{const}\cdot c+a_{2}x+b_{2}$$
$$\therefore~~~\text{const}=a^{-1}$$
$$\text{RHS}=x^{2}+\frac{b}{a}x+\frac{c}{a}+a_{2}x+b_{2}$$

$$=x^{2}+\left(\frac{b}{a}+a_{2}\right)x+\left(\frac{c}{a}+b_{2}\right)$$
$$\therefore~~~ \begin{equation*} \begin{cases} a_{2}=-\frac{b}{a}\\  b_{2}=-\frac{c}{a}\\ q\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{a} \end{cases} \end{equation*}$$
The current problem for me is as$~n\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq3}~$

$$q\left(x\right)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\text{const}_{i}x^{i}$$

$$x^{n}=\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\text{const}_{i}x^{i}\right)\left(ax^{2}+bx+c\right)+a_{n}x+b_{n}$$
$$=\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\text{const}_{i}x^{i}\right)ax^{2}+\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\text{const}_{i}x^{i}\right)bx+\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\text{const}_{i}x^{i}\right)c+a_{n}x+b_{n}$$

$$=a\underbrace{\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\text{const}_{i}x^{i+2}\right)}_{\max(i+2)=n}+b\underbrace{\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\text{const}_{i}x^{i+1}\right)}_{\max\left(i+1\right)=n-1}+c\underbrace{\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\text{const}_{i}x^{i}\right)}_{\max\left(i\right)=n-2}+a_{n}x+b_{n}$$

$$=a\left(\text{const}_{n-2}x^{n}+\underbrace{\sum_{i=0}^{n-3}\text{const}_{i}x^{i+2}}_{\max\left(i+2\right)=n-1}\right)+b\underbrace{\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\text{const}_{i}x^{i+1}\right)}_{\max\left(i+1\right)=n-1}+c\underbrace{\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\text{const}_{i}x^{i}\right)}_{\max\left(i\right)=n-2}+a_{n}x+b_{n}$$
$$=a\cdot\text{const}_{n-2}x^{n}+\underbrace{a\underbrace{\sum_{i=0}^{n-3}\text{const}_{i}x^{i+2}}_{\max\left(i+2\right)=n-1}+b\underbrace{\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\text{const}_{i}x^{i+1}\right)}_{\max\left(i+1\right)=n-1}+c\underbrace{\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\text{const}_{i}x^{i}\right)}_{\max\left(i\right)=n-2}+a_{n}x+b_{n}}_{\text{Unable to generate}~x^{n}~\because~x^{\max\left(\text{index}\right)}=x^{n-1}}$$
$$\therefore~~~a\cdot\text{const}_{n-2}=1~~\iff~~\text{const}_{n-2}=\frac{1}{a}$$
The current remaining problem for me is to derive the following equation.

$$0=a\underbrace{\sum_{i=0}^{n-3}\text{const}_{i}x^{i+2}}_{\max\left(i+2\right)=n-1}+b\underbrace{\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\text{const}_{i}x^{i+1}\right)}_{\max\left(i+1\right)=n-1}+c\underbrace{\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\text{const}_{i}x^{i}\right)}_{\max\left(i\right)=n-2}+a_{n}x+b_{n}$$
So the simplest way is to set$~\text{const}_{i}=0=a_{n}=b_{n}~$
However in [this equation1(of post of answer)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4304736/a-textmatrix-rightarrow-lim-n-to-inftyan-how-should-i-approac/4304807#4304807),$~a_{n}+b_{n}=1~$is held and my head has panicked.
I think I am missing the fundamental stuff.

Comment: $q(x)$ is the quotient of the [euclidean division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#Euclidean_division) of polynomial $x^n$ by polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $2$, where the remainder $a_nx+b_n$ has degree $\lt 2$ i.e. first degree. Note that you have a typo in $x^{n}= q\left(x\right)f\left(x\right) + a_{n} \color{red}{f\left(x\right)} + b_{n}$ $\;-\;$ that should be $\,x^{n}= q\left(x\right)f\left(x\right) + a_{n} \color{red}{x} + b_{n}\,$ instead.

Comment: I cleared that typo.